# Count condition within collection

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to find and show multiple data from list (using groovy) but the item to show depends on number of occurrences found.

I tried something like this (code below)
I tried also other ways to find the size of collection with `size()`, `length()` but nothing works.

```
list[list.findIndexValues { it == 'PA1-03-22'}.collect { it.count == 1 ? it+2 : it+1}]
```

Rigth now I always get error about count (No signature method ... ) but of course the target is to get proper item based on number of occurrences.

Comment: Hello. Can you please post the rest of the code? For example, the `it` in `it.count` refers to some class. Also the error you get.

Comment: Hi, since it is iReport groovy expression, there is not any other code (I simplified names of variables of list). Error is following: Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Long.count() is applicable for argument types: () values: []

Comment: Do you have an example input, and what output you'd expect?

Comment: I think you just want `findAll` instead of `findIndexValues`.  The later gives you list of _indices_ the predicate matches.  So you call `count` on a long (hence the error you are seeing)

Comment: Hi, here are inputs example: list[PA1-03-22,last_name_1,first_name_1,PA1-03-23,last_name_2,first_name_2....] output in case of one occurrance of code should be: last_name_1,first_name_1 and in case of multiple match I would like to output only last_name of all matched codes

Answer (score 0):

From your comments I figured out you want to achieve this:

```
def list = [    
                "PA1-03-22", "last_name_1", "first_name_1",
                "PA1-03-23", "last_name_2", "first_name_2",
                "PA1-03-22", "last_name_3", "first_name_3"
            ]

listnew = list.findIndexValues { it == 'PA1-03-22' }

listlast = []

if (listnew.size() == 1) {
    Integer index = listnew[0] + 1
    listlast = list[index]
} else {
    listnew.each {
        def element = list[it + 1]
        listlast << element
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `it` in this part of your code:

```
.collect { it.count == 1 ? it+2 : it+1}]
```

refers to the elements of:

```
list.findIndexValues { it == 'PA1-03-22' }
```

Namely `[0]`

and that is why you get the error.

I haven't used iReport but you could wrap it inside a closure this way:

```
def result = {
    def list = [    
                    "PA1-03-22", "last_name_1", "first_name_1",
                    "PA1-03-23", "last_name_2", "first_name_2",
                    "PA1-03-24", "last_name_3", "first_name_3"
                ]

    listnew = list.findIndexValues { it == 'PA1-03-22' }

    listlast = []

    if (listnew.size() == 1) {
        Integer index = listnew[0] + 1
        listlast = list[index]
    } else {
        listnew.each {
            def element = list[it + 1]
            listlast << element
        }
    }
    listlast
}

println(result())
```

Comment: Hello Victor,  thanks for answer. My problem is that I'm looking for one-line solution since I have to use it in iReport (sorry I did not specified it at begining). iReport does not allow in-expression declaration of variable (as far as I know). Thanks anyway for superb support.

Comment: Even if you wrap everything in a closure?. Look at the edit